# Function is undefined in JS object

Tags: javascript, scope

I create object `var myObj = new functon () {...}`. 
In that object i add functions like :

```
var myObj = new function () {
   this.func1 = function() {
       func2();
   }
   this.func2 = function() {
       ...
   }
}
```

As you can see in `func1` I try to call `func2` but it is always undefined. Why? Cause everything is in one object.

Comment: You need to call `this.func2()`

Comment: besides you dont need to use `new key word`

Comment: @ozil i guess OP need an object in `myObj` not a constructor function

Comment: Please correct functon => function

Comment: @RGraham, in this case i get error "Uncaught TypeError: this.func2 is not a function"

Comment: I wouldn't see why. At least not with the code you've posted - http://jsfiddle.net/gvcabz1e/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your scripts to

```
var myObj = function () {
   var self = this;

   this.func1 = function () {
       self.func2();
   };

   this.func2 = function () {
       ...
   };
};
```

Comment: I do not see a way without instantiating `myObj`

Comment: @Alexander, on page i call func1 like : `SessionTimeOut.initSessionTimeOutLogic('TimeOutMessage', 'lnkBtnSave', redirect_url, sessionKeep_alive_url, session_timeout_seconds, session_timeout_warning_seconds, session_timeout_check_interval_seconds);` and in it i call also func2

Answer (score 1):

You should call `func2` like this

```js
var myObj = new function () {
   this.func1 = function () {
       this.func2();
   }
   this.func2 = function () {
     console.log('func2');
   }
}

myObj.func1();
```

if you want call `func2` with `this.` and without, you can do it like this

```js
var myObj = new function () {
    function func2() {
        console.log('func2');
    } 
    
   this.func1 = function() {
       this.func2();
       func2();
   }
   
   this.func2 = func2;
}

myObj.func1();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's undefined because you don't have local variable `func2`. So correct reference should be `this.func2()`.

However even in this case your code is not *ideal* construction object like this (mixing constructor and anonymous function) (although *correct*). In this case it's better to use object literal in the first place rather then create constructor function for just creating one single object instance:

```
var myObj = {

    func1: function () {
        this.func2();
    },

    func2: function () {}
};
```

Comment: Well it is *syntactically* correct though isn't it? Just seems a bit redundant to `new` a singleton

Comment: This is the most appropriate answer - some detailed reading on why you definitely shouldn't new anonymous functions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782379/deathmatch-self-executing-anonymous-function-vs-new-function

Answer (score 1):

On top of solutions provided by others. If you are going to call a javascript function that is defined like this

```
var func = function(){}
```

the function definition needs to come before the function call.

In the other way of defining a function this does not matter.

```
function func(){}
```

So Overall Code should be

```
var myObj = function(){

   this.func2 = function(){
       ...
   }
   this.func1 = function(){
       func2();
   }

}
```

Comment: Please correct functon ==> function, and remove the new keyword.

Answer (score 0):

you can call like this.
Calling func2() directly, searches the function of window object.

```
var myObj = functon(){
   var current = this;
   this.func1 = function(){
       current.func2();
   }
   this.func2 = function(){
       ...
   }
};
```