# javascript: scoping and accessing nested entities

Tags: javascript, scope, nested

If we have this setup:

```
if (typeof(A) === 'undefined')
    A = {};

A.B = new function () {
   ....
   this.C = function () {
      ....
   }
}
```

what are some standard ways of accessing the `C` function from the outermost context (scope) ? I do have access to js sources so I can modify them accordingly.

Comment: Do you mean `A.B.C`?

Comment: [Never use `new function(){…}`!](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10406552/1048572)

Comment: You use `new function()` .... Really?

Comment: @Bergi A.B.C() yields "Object doesn't support this property or method" - IE8. Any hints ?

Comment: @kellogs: Unlikely. Can you show us the complete code you tried?

Comment: @Bergi It is the code from yvesmancera's answer below

Comment: @kellogs: He forgot the `new`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use new function(){} . Reason: [Deathmatch: Self Executing Anonymous Function -vs- "new function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782379/deathmatch-self-executing-anonymous-function-vs-new-function#9782779)

But anyway as you have not wrote this code, you are just editing an plugin file, so you can access C using A.B.C()

```
    <script>
        if (typeof(A) === 'undefined')
            A = {};

        A.B = new function () {
            this.C = function () {
                alert("I am c");
            }
        }

        A.B.C();
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

With only the code provided here, A is a [global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-function-of-the-var-keyword-and-when-to-use-it-or-omit-it), so you can access it within any scope as A.B.C();

```
if(typeof(A) === 'undefined') {
   A = {};
}
A.B = function() {

    this.C = function() {
        alert('A.B.C was called');
    };
};

A.B.C();
```