# Awkward way of executing JavaScript code

Tags: javascript

In the Google [tutorial for implementing Google+ sign-in in Flask application](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/python), I discovered that the developer often uses an awkward way of executing JavaScript code:

Instead of doing

```
var a = foo(bar);
```

I see this:

```
var a = (function() {
  return foo(bar);
})();
```

What is the reason to do it the weird way?

Comment: can you provide direct example. it depends on the situation

Comment: There's no reason to use that syntax there, and it doesn't appear on the page you link to. Could you link to the actual example so we can see the context?

Comment: Oh, ok, so it's just not to leave garbage of once needed but now obsolete variables behind.

Comment: @Quentin the actual code in the tutorial is very large and thus too specific to be included in the question.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This is a poor example. Consider the following:

```js
var a = (function() {
  var ret = {};
  ret.test = "123";

  function imPrivate() { /* ... */ }
  ret.public = function() {
    imPrivate();
  }
  return ret;
})();

console.log(a)
```

`a` will contain the varible test and the function public, however you can not access imPrivate. This is the common way to handle public vs private variables;

See [Why is this function wrapped in parentheses, followed by parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815757/what-exactly-is-the-point-of-this-function-construct-why-is-it-needed) for more info.

Answer (score 10):

```
var a = (function() {
  return foo(bar);
})();
```

In this case this is really unnecessary, but this is not wrong and it will not throw an error.

But `IIF` some times uses like `module pattern`:

```
var a = (function() {
  /* some other code in own scope */
  return foo(bar);
})();
```

In this case `IIF` is just a `module` which exports something outside.

Answer (score 2):

The closure function is used to encapsulate some of the attributes / methods in the function. Much like the private / public principle from other languages.

You can find more on this topic [here under Module Pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/)